# Make a clickable button from an image

Tags: button, processing

I am trying to implement a coumple of buttons in my sketch, so far so good. Keeping it simple I can just use rects to do so. But, I wonder if there is a way to load an image and use it as the texture for the button, I mean, make the image the button itself.I cannot find anywhere how to do this.

Comment: Are you using some kind of GUI library? If not- why can't you just check whether mouseX and mouseY are inside the image? If you want help, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run? (note: this should NOT be your entire sketch, just a small example!)

Comment: Thanks! it was the obvious thing to do, did not notice it at first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same logic you use for a rectangle with the image coordinates...

Something like:

```java
PImage button;
int bX = 150, bY = 150;
color c = randomColor();

void setup(){
  size (400,400);
  button = loadImage("http://dressitupembellishments.com/images/bulk_buttons/button/green_button.jpg");
  button.resize(100,0);
}
void draw(){
  background(c);
  image(button, bX, bY);
}


void mouseClicked(){
  if( mouseX > bX && mouseX < (bX + button.width) &&
      mouseY > bY && mouseY < (bY + button.height)){
        c = randomColor();
      };
    }

color randomColor(){
  return color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
}
```

Comment: although wrapping it as an ImageButton class and doing it the proper OO way would be even better.

Comment: Sure thing. It's an answer as generic as the question is... Just about the simple logic involved. However i might update it with an OO version when I get some time :)